# Scapy Segmentation Fault When Sending Packet

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, scapy

I have created a very basic program that repeatedly sends UDP packets but when executing it I have come across a reoccurring issue, I get a segmentation fault: 11 after a couple packets have sent, and I have executed the program with sudo on Mac OS X. Error Description:
Segmentation fault: 11

```
from scapy.all import *
while True:
    send(IP(src='192.168.1.101',dst='192.168.1.16')/UDP(dport=1050)/Raw(load='hi'))
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this error?